# Golang AWS SES email bad sender

Tags: go, email, amazon-ses

I am using the [AWS SES SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/ses-example-send-email.html) for Golang and it works as planned, but the only issue I have is that I send my emails from hi@domain.com so when the email is received in the `from` place I see `hi` instead of the domain name which I would prefer and I can't seem to find an easy fix for it. Has anyone encountered this? I think there should be an easy way to solve the issue. My code is almost identical to the linked sample in the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While providing `FromEmailAddress` in [SendEmailInput struct](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sesv2#SendEmailInput) try to use the following format `Nice sender name <sender@example.com>`, so to have the domain name you could have:

```
fromEmailAddress := "Example.com <sender@example.com>"
sesv2.SendEmailInput {
  FromEmailAddress: &fromEmailAddress, 
}
```